# Como leer y escribir acentos en archivos usando fs de Javascript?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, utf-8, filesystem, acentos

yo necesito leer un archivo .txt que contiene algunos acentos y ñ entre el texto, usando Javascript mediante la librería ya incluida FileSystem (fs). Pero cuando intento hacerlo, todas las letras con acentos y todas las ñ me salen con un signo de pregunta, entonces yo no puedo manipular un archivo .txt que tiene acentos, porque luego seran convertidas en signos de preguntas, y tengo que manualmente cambiarlas por su letra correspondiente.

Aca dejo el codigo que estoy utilizando:

```
const fs = require("fs");

function manipulateData(data){
    var formatedData = data.split(" ");
    fs.openSync("nuevoTexto.txt", "a");

    for (let i = 0; i < formatedData.length; i++){
        fs.appendFileSync("nuevoTexto.txt", formatedData[i] + "\r")
    }

}

fs.readFile("./textoLeer.txt", "utf-8", (err, data) => {manipulateData(data)})
```

Todo parece estar bien, pero cuando abro el archivo que genero, llamado "nuevoTexto.txt", todos los caracteres con acentos y todas las ñ me aparecen así: �

Una aclaración mas, el archivo original tiene la misma codificación (utf-8).

Alguien que sepa como resolverlo??? Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Perdón, ya lo resolví. El problema era que el archivo original no tenia una codificación de utf-8. Estaba usando ANSI.

Gracias igualmente